# android : Why I couldn't rotate antiClockwise?

Tags: android, canvas, matrix, bitmap, rotation

In my App I should rotate a picture like hand of clock clockwise and anticlockwise around bottom center.

I use this code :

```
private ImageView myImageView;
private float curScale = 1F;
private float curRotate = 70;
private Bitmap bitmap;
private int bmpHeight;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    myImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview);

    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.teste);//here you insert your image
    bmpHeight = bitmap.getHeight();
    drawMatrix();

} 
    private void drawMatrix() {
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    Matrix matrixb = new Matrix();
    Matrix matrixc = new Matrix();
    matrix.postScale(curScale, curScale);
    matrixb.setRotate(curRotate, 100, bmpHeight);
    matrixc.setTranslate(100, 0);
    matrix.setConcat(matrixb, matrixc);
    Bitmap targetBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(200, bmpHeight,
            bitmap.getConfig());
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(targetBitmap);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, matrix, new Paint());
    myImageView.setImageBitmap(targetBitmap);
}
```

But I couldn't rotate it anticlockwise because the width of picture change.
is there any solution?
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Just changing 100 to -100 in the `setRotate` method above should work - as long as it works properly clockwise.

Comment: @Jave: it doesn't work for me!